# Configuration system failed to initialise

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console application with a config file called `app.config`.  The full code behind by `app.config` file is as follows:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/>
    <add key="Server" value="0.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="DB" value="Test"/>
    <add key="UserName" value="testuser"/>
    <add key="Password" value="testuser"/>
    <add key="AgentEmail" value="test@gmail.com"/>
  </appSettings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
  </configuration>
```

When I try to run my application, I get an error : `Configuration system failed to initialize`.  Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any section group `<applicationSettings>` nor a section `<LeadDataEmail.Properties.Settings>` in your config file .... you've defined them in the `<configSections>` - now you need to actually **supply** them, too!

Comment: I have taken them out.  I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `configSections` from the file if you don't require it.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a section group and a contained section in your config here:

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" 
                    type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
         <section name="LeadDataEmail.Properties.Settings" 
                  type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </sectionGroup>
   </configSections>
```

That means, there **must be** a `<applicationSettings>` container, with a contained `<LeadDataEmail.Properties.Settings>` XML element in your `<configuration>`:

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>  
     ......
   </configSections>  

   <applicationSettings>
       <LeadDataEmail.Properties.Settings
           attribute1="value1"
           attribute2="value2" /> 
   </applicationSettings>
   ....
</configuration>
```

but I don't see any trace of that in your config file - no wonder the config system cannot initialize!

Comment: I have removed all the unnecessary info,  and updated my file above, still getting the error.

Comment: @user1668123: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.